# Problems overriding mod.member_settings.php email_prefs_form and update_un_pw_form

Tags: add-on-development, extension, module, authenticate

I have an extension and module that handles authentication for EE. I'm having some troubles understanding how to go about over-riding the handling in mod.member_settings.php. There is a hook for update|edit_user_preferences but it looks like it used to be that everything was under that hook. Sometime later they split things out but didn't add any additional hooks.

What I need to do is handle the email_prefs_form and update_un_pw_form. Ive thought of some ways I can think of doing this with the caveat that I don't how or if any of these are EE ways of doing things. One is to have the actions of the forms handled by my module/extension. Another is to trap sessions_end and try and return a view from my module's view directory (mod.member_settings seems to override any attempt to do this). Another might be to get hooks in mod.member_settings.php somehow to handle the submits.

Does anyone have any specific suggestions? I'm fairly new to EE so I don't really know what questions to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Are you *writing* your own extension? What for? There are plenty of existing extensions which will let you do pretty much anything with members. Perhaps we could better help by suggesting an add-on to use instead of writing something custom (check out [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember), [Authenticate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/authenticate), [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration), [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/), or [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit)).

The "EE way of doing things" is for your module to provide tags which allow other developers to completely customize the look and feel - that is why there is no easy way to return view files.

The built-in member module is a bit backwards in this regard, and doesn't follow the normal conventions to allow easy customization of the design. That is why so many add-ons have cropped up to replace the member module.

If you want an example of an EE authentication module, check out [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) - it's open source so should provide you with a good starting point.

Comment: Totally agree with Adrian. Use one of the existing add-ons, all the good ones have their own hooks you can use to do custom stuff if you need.